# CanActivate, Resolver for the dynamics urls (multiple nested dynamics segments)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, nested, angular2-routing

I build a web app which has a big part of dynamicly's generated pages. (99%).

Each page is simply a component with empty template where all data are provided from multiples services API through the url's slug.

The url can contain three nested levels, and each of these level have to correspond a logical nesting (from a contextual point of view, i mean... Friendly).

For example, an app which display some information about a country :

1. Regions - http://example.com/regions
2. Counties - http://example.com/regions/counties
3. Cities - http://example.com/regions/counties/city

Each of the tagname used by the url's have to translate to a valid imbrication name : http://example.com/south-east/greater-london/london like the russian dolls.

---

The router seem's to be like that :

```
{
    path: ':region-slug',
    component: RegionComponent,
    resolve: {
        region: RegionResolver
    }
},
{
    path: ':region-slug/:countie-slug',
    component: CountieComponent,
    resolve: {
        departement: CountieResolver
    }        
},
{
    path: ':region-slug/:countie-slug/:city-slug',
    component: CityComponent,
    resolve: {
        region: CityResolver
    }
}
```

First problem, the url can be anything, it'll be always true :

1. http://example.com/titi => true
2. http://example.com/qsdsqd/azeaz => true
3. http://example.com/titi/aze/toto156 => true
4. ...

So, I have to control the validity of each param to desserve the appropriate data stuffs of the template or redirect if the service founds anything.

Here is my first question :

1. Do I must using [Resolve](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Resolve-interface.html) or [CanActivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html) ?

I guess that this job is most appropriate for the Resolve interface. And I began to implement it for the first level (Region) with a "resolver" :

```
@Injectable()
export class RegionResolver implements Resolve<any>{

  constructor(private regionsService: RegionService, private router: Router) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {

    return this.regionsService
      .getRegion(route.params['region-slug'])
      .do(region => { 
        if(!region) this.router.navigate(['/404']);
      });
  }
}
```

And I get the corresponding data in the **RegionController** :

```
export class RegionComponent implements OnInit {

  region: Array<any> = [];

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.region = this.route.snapshot.data['region'];
  }
}
```

Easy for the moment, but the task begin more complex because if i apply the same behavior for all others levels, this kind of urls will programatically be correct :

1. http://example.com/south-east => true
2. http://example.com/sdfsdfsdfsd/greater-london => true
3. http://example.com/qsdq/toto54645/london => true
4. ...

So, question :

1. How I ensure myself that even if the current evaluate slug is true, the potential previous slug(s) is(are) correct too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, you're almost there: your route declarations and resolves seem fine.

Why don't you just validate the slugs FROM WITHIN the resolves and redirect to `/404` if the slugs are invalid?

You could create a function like this:

```
// validate-slugs.ts
/**
 * Return true if all given slugs are valid.
 */
export function are_slugs_valid(slugs: any): boolean {
  const validRegions = ['ile-de-france', 'nord-pas-de-calais'];
  const validCounties = ['val-de-marne', 'nord', 'pas-de-calais'];

  // Validate region slug
  if (slugs && slugs['region-slug'] && validRegions.indexOf(slugs['region-slug']) === -1) {
    return false;
  }

  // Validate county slug
  if (slugs && slugs['county-slug'] && validCounties.indexOf(slugs['county-slug']) === -1) {
    return false;
  }

  // @TODO: Validate city slug...

  return true;
}
```

And then use it in your resolves like so:

```
@Injectable()
export class RegionResolver implements Resolve<any>{

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    // NB. route.params contains ALL the slugs in the current route.
    if (!are_slugs_valid(route.params)) {
      this.router.navigate(['/404']);
    }
    // Proceed with fetching additional data...
  }
}
```

If the code for validating the slugs needs to be more sophisticated (e.g. make HTTP requests), convert the `are_slugs_valid()` function into a service and inject it in the resolve using DI.

I tried out the code I suggested, and I obtained the following behavior:

- http://localhost/ile-de-france - OK (displays `RegionComponent`)
- http://localhost/ile-de-france/val-de-marne - OK (displays `CountyComponent`)
- http://localhost/foo - 404
- http://localhost/foo/val-de-marne - 404
- http://localhost/ile-de-france/foo - 404

Let me know if you'd like to see the code.

**[EDIT] A few additional considerations:**

1) Since you're probably gonna hit a database to validate the slugs, you're gonna want to optimize that. Why don't you store ALL possible paths in your database?

```
ile-de-france
ile-de-france/val-de-marne
ile-de-france/val-de-marne/creteil
...
```

That way, for the deepest paths such as `ile-de-france/val-de-marne/creteil`, you only need ONE query to validate the three slugs contained in the path (`:region-slug`, `:county-slug`, and `:city-slug`).

2) If you add the `path` column to the same table where the entities (i.e. regions, counties, cities...) are stored, you only need one query to load the entity AND validate the path (the path acts as the entity's key).

Side note: if you follow my suggestion above, it makes sense to keep your code in a resolve, because it pre-loads some data AND does some validation, which is what resolves are for. If you just wanted to validate the path *without* preloading data, I'd probably put the code in a `CanActivate` service.